# Flutter - StatefulWidget and routes

Tags: flutter

How can i create a app with:

> StatefulWidget and routes in same code? In Flutter

I'll have it at same app. I can create it a various app separately, StatefulWidget and routes it will works but not at same time :/

My goal is a create a timer and change route to defrent view in the app

Here is my routes:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
    // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
    // on the FirstScreen widget.
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
  ));
}
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

hello You can use this method to redirect to any stateful widgets after your timer finishes execution.

```
void _redirectToPage(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      MaterialPageRoute newRoute =
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => page);

      Navigator.of(context)
          .push(newRoute);
    //or  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(newRoute, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found it's on this page here:

> https://kodestat.gitbook.io/flutter/flutter-basic-navigation-and-routes/routes-using-statefulwidget

Thats what i want.

```
setState(() {
  _counter++;
});
```

so i can update a Text and change view :)